# How do I unzip an xlsx file?

Tags: text-processing, zip

I found a command online that works for unzipping `docx` files but I haven't been able to tweak it to unzip `xlsx` files. The command is

```
unzip -p some.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g'
```

and I'm having trouble understanding the 2nd parameter `word/document.xml`, and how it's used.

When I tried converting an xlsx file, I tried:

```
unzip -p testexcel.xlsx excel/spreadsheet.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g'
```

but I have no idea what to put in that second parameter in place of `excel/spreadsheet.xml`.

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `unzip -t some.docx`?

Comment: You realize that's likely an Excel spreadsheet? What's your end-goal here?

Comment: End goal is to get all the text in the file. There are multiple spreadsheets as well. @steeldriver does that option list the available parameters? Looking at the man page, but it doesn't seem to help explain what it lists

Answer (score 5):

The parameter `word/document.xml` is the path of the file within the zip archive you are telling `unzip` to return. This is part of the standard structure of filetypes like docx.

For Excel xlsx files, you probably want `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`. If there are further worksheets, they are sheet2.xml, etc. This is regardless of the names you give the worksheets, which are stored in xl/workbook.xml along with general spreadsheet info.

If you're unsure of the zip file structure, you can use the `-l` option to list the files it contains.

`unzip -l some.docx`

Omitting the option just extracts the file to the current directory. The `-p` used in the command you're using pipes the output to stdout so sed can process it.

Answer (score 2):

You posted this command:

```
unzip -p some.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g'
```

First, to clarify what it does:

- it extracts a file called `word/document.xml` from the .docx file
- this it piped to the `sed` command which somehow "beautifies" the output by removing all formatting information

So, to find out how you can do this with an `.xlsx`, try `unzip foo.xlsx`. You can see now that the file you are interested in may be `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`.

But if you want to extract the content of an `.xlsx` I strongly recommend **not** to use this way.

There are several tools to convert an `.xlsx` to [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), which basically contains the content of the table sepperated by commas.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557360/convert-xlsx-to-csv-in-linux-command-line) has multiple answers how to convert form `.xlsx` to CSV.